# Recommendations for a good personal resume/portfolio website

Tags: looking-for-a-script, html5, jquery

Sorry for the broad question, but I am looking for some kind of package that will look great for posting up some personal details online in a resume type fashion. Possibly with the ability to add extra pages.

I've seen examples about, but not been too sure if they are running something specific or whether it is something custom.

I would generally just knock out a WordPress install but I don't think it will fit the bill.

Anything that utilizes current technologies would be great, i.e. HTML5, jQuery etc. I want the site to look smart and up to date.

Comment: Is this a group site where you can edit your profile? Or and individual site for one or 2 persons?

Comment: Sorry for the non-clarity. This would be for one person, under a personal domain.

Answer (score 2):

A good solution for one person under a personal domain is a plain html5 page(s), because you can design it with the mood you want.

There's plenty of free (as in freedom, not just price) html templates on the you you can start from, but I recommend that you start from a boilerplate html5 package like Gridless: http://thatcoolguy.github.com/gridless-boilerplate/

Keep it simple. Keep it focused on the goal of the page and in the page's audience needs.

Answer (score 1):

I am unsure if this will do, but this is my suggestion: http://carbonmade.com/.